# push notification with cordova and firebase Cloud messaging:registrationID keep changing

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using cordova plugin `ktekosi-phonegap-plugin-push`, I get the `registrationID`

```
var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "my sender ID"}});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    console.log(data.registrationId);
    document.getElementById("fcm_id").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
});
```

So I can use it by the server to send notification through FCM.

How can I get this `registrationID` fixed for all time? Is this an app specific ID or a user specific ID?

Comment: What problem are you getting??? changing of registration id or sending message

Comment: when i load the app with this this code above the registrationID is changing with time

Comment: is ithis ID a appID or an 'instance of the installed app' ID. in aother words is it app specific or user specific?

Comment: If you install app once then it should remain same unless there is new update OR re-install app. Otherwise every time you open app, it remains same.

Comment: mm i just reopened the app and it was another registrationID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push registration ID will be changed with time. This is an usual case. This is neither an instance of the installed application nor app-specific or user-specific id.

When an app comes online you need to fetch the push registration ID and then pass it to your backend server each time to keep your backend server updated with the push registration ID.

Your backend server will then generate a push notification and will send it to FCM with the specific push registration ID it has. FCM then manages receiving the push notification in your mobile application.

I've [answered a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41024102/3145960) telling how push notification system works. You might have a look.

**Update**

Looks like google has changed its new gcm library as the answer stated here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839326/3145960. You might take a look at here. So, as I've read, the push registration id is updated only when app receives an update or the android os gets updated. Its much simpler now.

Comment: thanks reaz! can u precise what u mean by 'app comes online' and 'each time'.

Comment: Application comes online and each time means the same actually. When you launch your application each time, you need to get the push registration ID first and have to send it to the server to keep the server updated with the latest push registration ID as I have stated before.

Comment: ok thanks . what i quite don't understand is when exactly the registrationID is updated but thanks to u i have understood u need to keep a bi-directional communication between the server and the app

Comment: Great to know that helped! We don't actually know when the registration ID is updated. We don't actually have to bother about it too.

Comment: well if the user dont lauch application for a long time it might stop getting notifications then if its been updated in the meantime, no?

Comment: Looks like google has changed its new gcm library as the answer stated here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16839326/3145960. You might take a look at here. So, as I've read, the push registration id is updated only when app receives an update or the android os gets updated. Its much simpler now.

Comment: i actually use fcm

Comment: FCM's core is composed of GCM itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this plugin "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm". You can find detail [here](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)

To get Registration ID Use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function onLoad() {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", Fire, false);
                               }

            function Fire() {

                FCMPlugin.getToken(
                  function (token) {

                       alert(token)
                  },
                  function (err) {
                           alert("Error: " + 'error retrieving token: ' + err);
                  }
                );

            };


        </script>
 <body onload="onLoad();">
```